# How to give some trusted person access to an Azure AKS instance without access to the Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

Assuming having access to an Azure subscription with a fully configured Azure Kubernetes Service, via

```
az login
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
az aks browse --resource-group somegroup --name somecluster
```

i can get access to Kubernetes Dashboard.

Is there a way to give temporary access to Kubernetes Dashboard to some person who does not have access to the Azure Subscription the AKS is associated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, just create appropriate kubernetes config (so the user can port-forward the dashboard pod) to the cluster and then the user will be able to connect to the dashboard.

Comment: Do you have an example or reference at hand?

Comment: Find a working example here: https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/working-with-kubeconfig